# How to store all frames from a sequence with OpenCV (c++)?

Tags: c++, opencv, mp4

I've tried to seperate a frame-sequence from a movie like this:

```
void storeSequence() {
Mat frame;

VideoCapture vid("myVideo.mp4");

if (!vid.isOpened()) {
    return;
}

int fps = 30;
int count = 0;
bool cut = false;

vector<Mat> frames;

bool capture = true;

while (capture) {

    vid >> frame;
    imshow("video", frame);

    char character = waitKey(1000 / fps);

    Mat outMat;

    switch (character) {
            case 'c':
        cut = !cut;
        break;
    case 27:
        return;
    case 'x':
        capture = false;
    }
    if (cut) {
        frame.copyTo(outMat);
        frames.push_back(outMat);
        count++;
    }
    if (!capture) break;
}

cout << count << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    stringstream fn;
    Mat img = frames[i];
    fn << "seq1_" << i << ".jpg" << endl;
    imwrite(fn.str(), img);
}

}
```

The video is displayed and after I pressed c two times, followed by x the console tells me how many frames are stored in the vector "frames", but no image gets written in my filedirectory. What am I missing? (Or is there an even better option to seperate a sequence?)

Comment: Are you sure your video fps is 30? Why don't use vid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)?

Comment: I'd use [`avconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/avconv.1.html) for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change   `fn << "seq1_" << i << ".jpg" << endl;`to   `fn << "seq1_" << i << ".jpg";`
When You add endl at the end Yout string looks like this `"seq1_0.jpg\n"`ant this is wrong path.